# Impressão de etiquetas pulando de 2 em 2

Tags: delphi

Estou gerando uma aplicação que lee um `txt` , e gera etiquetas para serem impressas no momento em que estou usando uma argox
com o código abaixo recebo e faço a impressão das etiquetas:

```
var x: string;
var y,i : integer;
begin
begin
   for i := 0 to count do
   begin
    button1.visible := false;
    label1.caption := form1.memo1.lines[i];
    label2.Caption := form1.memo7.lines[i] ;
     label9.Caption := form1.memo2.lines[i];
     label10.Caption := form1.memo3.lines[i];
    label11.Caption := form1.memo4.lines[i];
     label13.Caption := form1.memo5.lines[i];
    label14.Caption := form1.memo6.lines[i];
    GerarCodigo(label1.caption, Image1.Canvas);
   PrintScale :=  poNone;
   Print;
   end;
```

ele deixa 2 etiquetas em branco, e imprime corretamente e assim vai.

Percebi que a fila de impressão é preenchida pelas requisições, acredito que esse seja o motivo.

Para exemplificar melhor o que ocorre quando vou imprimir
fiz um desenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe uma maneira de armazenar e enviar tudo de uma vez?
ou alguma alteração no código que altere isso?

Answer (score -1):

Acho que voce precisa definir a altura da etiqueta e o espaço vertical entre elas, se houver. Dependendo da versão do Delphi que você está usando, talvez você tenha o quick report. Se este for o seu caso, tente usá-lo. Nele você poderá criar e gerar etiquetas fácilmente.

Comment: não estou usando banco de dados,existe alguma outra menira?

Comment: Duas respostas?

Comment: Jose, junta suas duas respostas em uma só, assim você consegue contextualizar e passar uma resposta mais completa para quem pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

O seu problema é com a configuração da etiqueta. Uma vez que você não está informado nda a impressora segue um padrão pré ajustado. Tente configurar o formato(Altura x largura, tamanho da folha, etc.) no setup da impressora, ou através do seu código.

Se quiser informe o modelo da sua impressora e dou uma olhada no manual dela para ver se tem como ajustar isto no setup.

Comment: Argox OS-214 plus, eu coloquei o form nas medidas da etiqueta 10x5...snedo assim ele nao deveria sair no tamanho correto?

Comment: Veja este link : http://www.manualslib.com/manual/9337/Argox-Os-214-Plus.html?page=28#manual. Tente configurar para o tamnho da sua etiqueta. Se não existir o tamanho , escolha custom e entre as medidas da sua etiqueta. Tambem  no inicio do manual fala sobre acalibração da impressora. Faça a calibration( reset e depois calibre)  antes de setar o tamanho da sua etiqueta.